# How to cancel a cloudKit operation due to timeout in Swift?

Tags: swift, timeout, cloudkit, nsoperation

I am looking for help about how to cancel a cloudKit operation due to a given timeout setting? My case is I use CKModifyRecordsOperation upload some changes to iCloud, if failed, I will save those failed records to local storage. But something, the operation will take so long time...

So, I want to set a timeout about 60 seconds on that operation, then if timeout, I will cancel that operation. Now I just use sleep func, though this is not in main thread, it makes every added operation run at least 60s. I know this is not the right solution. My code like below:

```
let uploadOperation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: recordsToSave, recordIDsToDelete: recordIDsToDelete)
uploadOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { (savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error) in
    if let error = error {
        ...
        CloudKitManager.persistentFailedRecords(saveFailed, deleteFailed)
    } 
}

CloudKitManager.privateDB.add(uploadOperation)    

sleep(60)
if uploadOperation.isExecuting {
    uploadOperation.cancel()
}
```

I did some search about timeout on an operation, the answer mainly focus on NSURLSession, no answer for CloudKit operation. And I tried with its own property "timeoutIntervalForRequest", but it doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Did you set it properly?:

```
let operationConfiguration = CKOperation.Configuration()

operationConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60
operationConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60

let fetchRecordZoneChangesOperation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation()

fetchRecordZoneChangesOperation.configuration = self.operationConfiguration

// etc...
```